# usage of zip function in for statement in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to modify some python code from this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/18/multiple-cameras-with-the-raspberry-pi-and-opencv/#comment-448898) to suit my needs. Anyone know how can I modify the following for statement to eliminate the picam and piMotion variables as I am not going to use them?

```
for (stream, motion) in zip((webcam, picam), (camMotion, piMotion)):
```

I have tried:

```
for (stream, motion) in zip(webcam, camMotion):
```

But get:

> for (stream, motion) in zip(webcam, camMotion):
>   TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Comment: What are the values of `webcam` and `camMotion`? Are they iterable?

Comment: We need more information--a complete code snippet, to be precise. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are _most likely_ looking for `stream=webcam; motion=camMotion`, followed by the rest of your code (with no `for` loop whatsoever).

Comment: webcam = VideoStream(src=0).start()

camMotion = BasicMotionDetector()

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
webcam = [0,1,2]
cammotion = [3,4,5]
tup_lst = [(webcam, 'picam'), (cammotion, 'piMotion')]

for stream,motion in zip(*[x[0] for x in tup_lst]):
    print(stream,motion)
```

**Output:**

```
(0, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 5)
```